# error: expected expression before '/' token

Tags: c

I'm no C expert, and am getting this error when trying to cross-compile a C application:

```
src/ls_sqlite3.c:522: error: expected expression before '/' token
```

The offending line is this:

```
sqlite3_busy_timeout(conn, lua_tonumber(L,3)); // TODO: remove this
```

I suspect the use of // for comments is not allowed by certain compilers or through some settings, but Google didn't help. Does someone know?

Thank you.

Comment: Strict C compilers do not accept C++ style comments.

Comment: Indeed there is only `/* ... */` for commenting in good old C (I don't remember the exact version).

Comment: I thought that // was a C++ style comment, available as from C99.  Maybe your compiler follows C89?

Comment: @steabert: I've discovered that gcc frowns upon C++ style comments when called with `-std=c99 -pedantic`

Comment: weird, from `man gcc`: "For example -std=gnu89 -pedantic would warn about C++ style // comments, while -std=gnu99 -pedantic would not."

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the old C standard only allowed comments are `/*...*/`. Only from C99 standards onwards `//` are allowed as comments.

Comment: Thanks everyone. The original Makefile did use "-ansi": Replacing this with "-std=c99" solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Since you didn't mention your compiler. You could change it to c-style comments

```
sqlite3_busy_timeout(conn, lua_tonumber(L,3)); /* TODO: remove this */
```

Check your compilers manual for a compatibility switch for c++ style comments.